# Cross-platform UI markup language for iOS, Android and WP8?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, windows-phone-8, markup

Are there any cross-platform UI markup languages for major mobile operating systems? I'm mainly looking for a language for describing forms and other interactive elements.

HTML won't do because the requirement is that the UI is built using each device's native widgets for everything in the view.

Comment: No, there is nothing like this, unless you're looking to use PhoneGap

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could try one of the many multi platform toolkits like:

- Appcelerator Titanium mobile http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/
- APPlause https://github.com/applause/APPlause
- Appmobi XDK  http://www.appmobi.com/
- Canappi  http://www.canappi.com/
- Kony         http://www.konysolutions.com/konyone
- Marmalade    http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/
- Mobl         http://www.mobl-lang.org/
- Orubase  http://www.orubase.com
- PhoneGap http://phonegap.com/
- Red Foundry  http://www.redfoundry.com/
- StackMob https://dashboard.stackmob.com/
- Steape   http://www.steape.com/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MarkupKit:

https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit

It's an open-source framework I wrote that allows you to build native iOS apps in markup. It isn't cross-platform, but it provides a similar development metaphor to XAML and Android. For example, you can create a label instance like this:

```
<UILabel text="Hello, World" font="System 24" textColor="#ff0000"/>
```

rather than this:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];

[label setText:@"Hello, World"];
[label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

Obviously, that's a simple example - the value of using markup becomes much more apparent with more complex view hierarchies. It also supports dynamic localization and CSS-like styling.

You can find articles and examples on my blog:

https://gkbrown.wordpress.com

Hope you find it useful.